# How to call services from Spark worker processes

Tags: java, apache-spark

A spark RDD computation work, which I'm trying to implement, is relatively complicated and includes calls to a few service classes (which, in its turn, calls external services).

But when I'm trying to make these service calls from a closure inside, say, JavaSparkContext::map or JavaSparkContext::forEach, I'm getting java.io.NotSerializableException.

What is the right way to implement computation, which involves external service calls, in Spark?

Comment: Can you describe why you'd want to call the external service? I assume the classes involved are not serializable and hence the issue. One workaround could be to save the partial results and ping the service to use them. If however you need to enhance the results, you may want to use broadcasts or accumulators to let "others" know there's something to process.